# What happens to a question that is removed from StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I recently had [a question "removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450429/historical-weather-forecasts)

The question was fairly old, and actually had some useful answers.  Is there any way to find a deleted question and re-read the answers, so I can continue to use this useful reference?

Also, is there a way to protest the removal, or at least ask for some clarity as to what was inappropriate about the question?

Comment: [tag:weather] eeew

Answer (score 2):

The question was removed because it was a [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) that attracted "Me too" "answers". Users with [10 000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) can see deleted questions.

The tutorial answer you probably want was [Importing Weather Data from Wunderground](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/991). The other answer was proposing Weathernation and Feedsyndicate.

Comment: I disagree, as I believe only only one of the 4 answers was a "me too" answer.  One of the other answers contained a possibly useful link that I unfortunately can no longer see.

Comment: There was three answers of which one was a "me too". Some links was in the comments as well, which I believe emphasise the fact that this was a bad question (people giving answers in comments because they aren't really "answers" but rather "shopping suggestions"). The "Me too" answer made a moderator aware of the problematic question and so he removed it.

Comment: Responding to your edit: thank you for the links.  While the tutorial answer was useful, it only applied to historic weather data, not historic weather forecasts.  I know that the National Weather Service publishes the national digital forecast database, which I believe contains historic as well as current forecasts.  I've never found a programmatic way to access that data-- perhaps I could re-word my question and ask it again?